# How to serialize integers and delimiter bits in a single data structure?

Tags: java, serialization

I want to serialize a binary tree, but instead of nulls, I want to save a single bit.
Example, consider a simple binary tree, node with value 1 and 2 children left is of value 2 and right is of value 3. I want to serialize it like 1 2 . . 3 . . 
I was thinking of converting all integers into bits, and for dots I want to store just a single bit.
Which data structure in java can I use to convert and int to bits and interspace them with set bits ?

Comment: How will your deserialisation algorithm distinguish bits that you have used for dots from bits that are part of an integer?

Comment: You could use something resembling Huffman encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want the other side to deserialize anything but bytes (anything smaller than bytes). I would serialize nulls as the integer -1 and use positive integers for numbering the nodes. This way your serialization method would be clear, uniform, and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @peter.petrov, the best way would be to use integers for nodes and -1 for nulls.

I think is impossible use only 1 bit to represent a null value, because when you deserialize you won't be able to distinguish a node from a null value (keeping in mind that this is a stream).

But, if for any reason you "need" to deal with bits, the only way I can think to do that would be to use a sequence of bits for nulls as delimiter (0000 in example). This delimiter must have a known size.

If your binary tree has 15 nodes, you will need 4 bit for represent it (2^4=16, 15 binary values for nodes and one for null). Be careful if you don't know how many nodes has your tree, or if it can grows.

However, I think this is too much difficult and complicated than use simply integers for nodes and -1 for nulls.